# Query to get the users who have a application approved

Tags: mysql-5.5

I have two tables Users and Submissions . Need to find the query to get the users who have submitted atleast one grant and have never won .

I can write a subquery and achieve it .But I would like to know if there is an efficient way ?

```
Users 
ID | name | email | registered | etc



Submissions 

ID | userID | status | eventID | etc
```

Now Submissions can have multiple entries of users corresponding to different event. A user can have a status as approved ,rejected .

How do I write the MySQL query to fetch the users who have atleast one submission but never approved .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the same table twice, once to check that there exists some submission (preferably a rejected one) and second time you left join the same to get any approved submission - then you can check if the left join found something (and remove those - `where approved_table.id is null`) - to get only one row per user you can do a `group by Users.ID`.

```
select users.* from users
inner join Submissions exist_grant
    on users.ID = exist_grant.userID
left join Submissions approved_grant
    on (approved_grant.status="Approved" and users.ID = approved_grant.userID)
where approved_grant.userID is null
group by users.ID
```

Comment: Can you write the query ? select * from users 
inner join Submissions exist_grant on users.ID = exist_grant.userID
left join Submissions approved_grant on users.ID = approved_grant.userID
where approved_grant.status="Approved" and approved_grant.userID is null

Comment: the above query doesnt work

Comment: @rrmo you need to check the "approved" condition in ON for a left join to work the way it should. I modified your query a bit. The first join ensures that at least one submission exists, the second one in combination with the where checks that no approved submission exists and the group by resolves "multiplying" of users who have more than one submission.